# Updating comment count of the article on comment prepersist properly, with services

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Article and Comment entity (oneToMany)

On Comment prepersist lifecycle event I would like to count how many comments there are for this article and update Article's comment_count field.

If I understand symfony2 approach correctly, I need to write a service for this. Let's call it CommentCountManager.

My question is: How exactly do I make container available in entity so that I can get the CommentCountManager and triger the funciton that count comment for given article, and how do I access Doctrine's entity manager in my CommentCountManager so that I can actually run queries there?

Am I on the right path?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the comments count in a separate column — you can count them on output. What you are trying to do is denormalization and I recommend avoiding it unless you absolutely need it for performance reasons — and only when you are *sure* that *that* part is causing the problems. But even then, query optimization and caching are much better alternatives to denormalization.

Making entities aware of the container is a bad idea too. If you need this, then you are doing something wrong.

To access an entity manager in a service, you need to [inject](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) it.